# Switch google charts type with multiple charts on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, google-visualization

I have a page with 10 google charts on it. I have a button designed to switch the chart type, but as it is currently written, it only changes one chart at a time. If I built that for every different chart, I would be repeating a ton of code.

What I would like to do is write a more general function that will change the type of chart for any individual div instead of the current 1.

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5D68/1/) with all the code as it is currently implemented.

```
var redrawCombo = function(){
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],
   ['2004',  1000,      400],
   ['2005',  1170,      460],
   ['2006',  660,       1120],
   ['2007',  1030,      540]
  ]);

var options = {
  title: 'Company Performance',
  hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'},
  'height': 250,
  animation: {
    duration: 750,
    easing: 'out',
  },
 }
};
var chart = new google.visualization.ComboChart(document.getElementById('chart_div1'));
chart.draw(data, options);
}
// Click Handlers
$('#combo-chart').click(function(e){
  redrawCombo();
  return false;
});
$('#bar-chart').click(function(e){
  drawChart1();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: Like this?? http://jsfiddle.net/robertrozas/j7nR7/

Comment: What I would like is for the click handler to find out which div it is in, then pass that into a function which redraws the map with whatever is selected. That way I can click on any of the graphs and have it change with one function instead of one built for each.

Answer (score 0):

You could write a single event handler that attaches to all elements matching a selector (perhaps a class for your chart divs would be good for this?), and use the event properties to retrieve the clicked container:

```
$('.myCharts').click(function (e) {
    // e.target is the clicked on element
    // container id is e.target.id
});
```